# Is it possible to get email on my shared hosting domain (Verio) which were sent to a different (unhosted) domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, emailrelay

I have a website "example.com" with email user "anyname". I also have a domain name "other.com" with zone records pointing to "example.com". if I email "anyname@other.com" I get either a user not found or a relay not allowed message.

I have found no way to modify "other.com"s MX records to allow this.
I have also played with mod rewrite to no good effect.

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with the web server or `.htaccess` style files. You are talking about email messages, so you have to take a look at the email servers, not the web server! Specifically you have to modify the smtp server which receives the email, it has to accept messages to that remote domain which it refuses currently out of security reasons. Please learn how email messages are exchanged in the internet first, you will not understand what you have to do otherwise.

Comment: I can view and modify the web site with ftp, but I have no idea how to find or modify the smtp server.

Comment: As said: you will have to learn about the matter first. There is little sense if anyone here tries to explain all of that to you in a question and answer session. No way. Either find someone who does that stuff for you or sit down and learn. Start by using google and learn what smtp is.

Comment: Further: I do know from one of the error messages that the email is being handled by QMAIL, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: QMail is a mta software, so it can act as an smtp server. This is a good starting point for your google research...

Comment: Well since this is not a private or virtual private website, it may well be that I have no way to diddle with the smtp server in which case the problem is not solvable. I find it hard to believe that the ability to do this is not a frequently desired wish.

Comment: It certainly is a frequent issue that is solved. Why not? Such setups are used in numbers of millions out there on the internet. But if you want to modify the behaviour of an smtp server you are using you have to be able to do so. There is no magic in that. You might want to think about runniing your own server, a virtual one will do. Then you have control over _all_ aspects of that system. But there is a downside: you have to configure, secure and maintain _all_ aspects of that system too... Or you can simply ask your hosting provider if he can do the setup for you...

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your helpful comments. My hosting provider says that this is not possible. I'm going to take the easiest solution which is to either get a cheap mail forwarder or a cheap domain from some provider to forward to my "real" domain.